# I want when i click on a link, a php script Be executed and store the data on the database that i can use them

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code in `2.html` page

```
<a href='1.php' >click me</a>
```

I want, when i click on this link, this lines run in `1.php` page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            my page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        include('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html=file_get_html($url);
        foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
            $html2=$element->href;
        }
```

I want to store `$html2` in database then it be returned to my first   page. be easy on me. any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code into the bracket after $html2

```
$html2=$element->href;

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyDataTable (htmlcontent)
VALUES ($html2)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();

header("Location:myfirst.php");
die();
```

Comment: i know how to save the data . i want to use them in html2 page

Comment: You can use the blog data type for saving the HTML page